# Two date columns, one date. How can I get the data?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have the following problem:

In mysql I have a table which contains two date columns start_date and end_date. The date format is yyyy-mm-dd. What I am trying to do is to get all data from all the rows where a specific date, lets say '2012-03-05' mateches one of these date columns or are something in between.

How can I create a good sql-query that gets the data needed? I've checked on the between statement but I don't really know if that's the best way to go. I guess this is generally a simple task but I just can't figure a good query out.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess I could do something like select * from test where start_date <= '2012-03-05' AND end_date >= '2012-03-05'. But is there a better way?

Comment: When you have an interval with `start_date`/`end_date` ends, usually only one of these ends is *inclusive*; the other one is *exclusive*. This is done to ensure that multiple records do not match a query with the same date. Which one is inclusive and which one is not depends on your database design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= '2012-02-29' AND end_date >= '2012-02-29';
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought about that model. It just took some time for it to sink down. :)

Comment: This would do it also, although if you were to SELECT something FROM **TABLE** you'd get a syntax error ;-)

Comment: ... I would assume he knows to replace that with his actual table name.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common way to structure your tables with ranges of dates, especially in [temporal database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) designs. It lets you perform range-based queries very efficiently, assuming that indexes on both columns exist. You query the data like this:

```
select *
from mytable t
where t.start_date <= @desired_date and t.endDate > @desired_date
```

`@desired_date` is the date for which you would like to query, e.g. '2012-03-05'.

Note the `<=` on one side and `>` on the other side, without `=`. This is done to ensure that the from-to ranges define non-overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, try something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    '2012-03-05' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE '2012-03-05' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Comment: I like that version best. Thanks :)